# use.latest.version configuration not working for kafka producer and schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a kafka cluster configured locally along with a schema registry instance, and I am a bit confused regarding use.latest.version configuration. From what I read in the documentation, this configuration enforces the serializer of a producer to use the latest version of a schema registered in the schema registry, regardless the schema that the object being serialized uses.

I have the following configuration for my Java producer, which tries to send avro serialized values:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
properties.setProperty("auto.register.schemas", "false");
properties.setProperty("use.latest.version", "true");
```

Once I try to send objects for a schema version that is not registered yet, it fails (which is reasonable since auto.register.schemas configuration is set to false). However, if I have two versions of a schema registered for this topic value (v1 and v2) and I try to send objects of schema v1, the records that I consume are serialized with v1 instead of using v2 which is the latest one. FYI, I have a kafka file sink connector that consumes the records for debugging purposes. Is there something wrong with the configuration from my side or I don't understand the actual use of this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, in order for this to work, I used kafka avro serializer and kafka connect of version 7.4.0. `use.latest.version` configuration does not exist in versions prior to 7.4.0.

Using a producer, when I try to send records of schema v1 and `use.latest.version` is enabled, it fails to serialize the object since the latest schema version is not compatible to the one of the object being serialized. The only way to send a record when `use.latest.version` is enabled, is by configuring a specific compatible schema for serialization using `use.schema.id` configuration.

On the other hand, if I enable the `use.latest.version` configuration on the consumer side, it fetches the records (serialized either using schema v1 or v2) and deserializes them using the latest v2 schema (by applying any default values and data type changes). However, if `use.latest.version` is disabled in the consumer side, then all the records are deserialized using the same schema version that are serialized with.
So, in conclusion, all the work for making the schema evolving lies on the deserializer side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the last three settings there with `value.serializer.` since those are properties of it, not the ProducerConfig. In fact, you should be seeing logs saying just that - they're unknown configs to the producer

> the records that I consume are serialized with v1 instead of using v2

Unclear how you're consuming, but if you use SpecificRecord type, then you'd compile a specific version, yes.

Otherwise, GenericRecord would consume *both versions*. Kafka Connect would do the same as well to construct a Struct type for each version, assuming you're using Avro record schemas

Comment: You were right about the `use.latest.verion` configuration but not for the rest of them. I also added the configuration you mentioned as prefixed but I got the following warning log in my producer:
`WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - These configurations '[value.serializer.schema.registry.url, use.latest.version, value.serializer.auto.register.schemas, value.serializer.use.latest.version]' were supplied but are not used yet.`
So I guess `use.latest.version` is not used in any way.

Comment: The way that I consume is the classic one that kafka connect does. I haven't added any extra configuration, since I know that the schema version selection is on the serializer (producer) side.

Comment: I am correct, though. That's how all my projects are written, and it works great... ProducerConfig indeed does not have those configurations. It's a warning, not an error... It's just a feature of the Kafka API to first pass all properties to the producer, whether they're accepted or not. The fix would be to explicitly call configure function on a new serializer instance, not pass just a class name

Comment: Based on the source this looks like it should be correct as @OneCricketeer states.  Please report back if this works since we are experiencing the same problem: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java#L136-L139C52

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't see any change by providing this configuration to the producer (either prefixed or not). @OneCricketeer Can you please provide some more info regarding your producer, for instance what is its whole configuration, how you send your data, an example of an old and a new schema?

Comment: Not sure what producer changes you're asking about. If you simply want to remove that warning, you would do `Serializer<?> serializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer<?>()`, for example, then call `serializer.configure(props)` with a separate properties object, and then `properties.setProperty("value.serializer", serializer);`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am not asking about changes, but details on how your producer is configured and set in order to make this work. I am not asking for removing the warning (its the least that I care tbh).  As described in the question, I am trying to send old data (of schema v1) serialized with the latest schema (schema v2), automatically when use.latest.version configuration is enabled. Unfortunately, this hasn't worked so far for me.

Comment: @AlexandrosMavrommatis The source code is linked above for how that property is used. You need to set `value.serializer.auto.register.schemas+false`, and same serializer prefix for registry url and `use.latest.version=true`. And make sure you use latest release of `kafka-avro-serializer`... I never tried to make a producer "use latest version" because all my producers had specific compiled classes, i.e. versions to them. It was the consumer's responsibility to do schema evolution and protect the schema forward to the version it needed (or latest version)

Comment: Even in the logs, you should see SerializerConfig / AvroConfig with the values you've set

Comment: @OneCricketeer it was actually a version issue. `use.latest.version` configuration actually works from version 7.4.0 and upwards. It doesn't need `value.serializer` prefix to work. But despite what the documentation states, it is not just a matter of serializer configuration. The actual work of using the latest schema version lies on the consumer (deserializer) side. I will post answer to the question, describing all the details of it. Thanks for the info

Comment: @AlexandrosMavrommatis The prefix ensures the property is correctly passed to the respective class (serializer, for example), rather than the kafka clients (producer/consumer).